# Show that:$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}} \geq n^2 $

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, inequality, induction

Show that:$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}} \geq n^2 $$
The following hints are also given: $$\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \geq 2 \right) \land x,y \gt 0$$

**Base Case:** For n = 2

$$\left(1+2\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \geq 2^2$$

**Inductive hypothesis:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x_{i}} \geq \left(n+1\right)^2 = n^2+2n+1$$

**Inductive step:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x_{i}} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}+(n+1)\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right) + \left((n+1) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}\right) + (n+1) \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}$$

**Final words:**

I came to the conclusion that:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right) = n^2$$

I inserted for n = 1 so that $$\left((n+1) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right) = \frac{2}{1} \land \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$ Since $$\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \geq 2 \right) \land x,y$$ was given as a hint in the beginning I thougt I can say that $$\left((n+1) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 2n$$

Furthermore it's obvious that: $$(n+1) \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} = 1$$

It's pretty standard proof by induction and I hope you can maybe give me some advices on what I could have done differently and verify the legitimacy of this proof.

Comment: Why was this down-voted ?

Comment: I don't know but I was a bit shocked when I saw that the question received a downvote 5 seconds after I have just posted it.

Comment: Does $x_i=i$ here?

Comment: @KeJie: this post is missing the motivation and application of the problem. Where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest?  You say that hints "are also given" - who gave the hints?

Comment: @KeJie: rather than giving partial and vague info, you can improve the post to be more direct about which exam, which class, and which book. There is no reason to leave out that info, but not including it is one reason why you may see downvotes.

Comment: @Carl Mummert "There is no reason to leave out that info" These kind of informations don't contribute anything useful to the question in my opinion. If that's really the reasons why im receiving downvotes I might just pass on all the math sites on the internet and only use books instead.

Comment: @KeJie: they help others know where you found the question, and they help others find the question by searching. They also help answers know the level of mathematics to use when answering the question.  There is more information at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960 about providing context for questions.

Comment: @Carl Mummert I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way :
It's a direct consequence of the inequality of [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) .

Comment: Thank you for sharing it I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

One must assume $\,x_i \gt 0\,$ otherwise the inequality doesn't necessarily hold true.

Once assumed that all $\,x_i\,$ are positive, this is just the AM $\ge$ HM mean inequality:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}}{n} \;\ge\; \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{i}}}$$

Comment: $$x_{i} \gt 0$$ Was also given. I forgot to mention this information in my question.